# How can I remove certain elements from a list during json deserialization?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, deserialization

Suppose we have an api call that gives me a list of objects (for example `Person (name: String, surname: String, age: String)`) and for an inconsistency of services (age in String in the first item and Int in the second) the response is:

```
{
   "people":[
      {
         "name":"Jon",
         "surname":"Snow",
         "age":"34"
      },
      {
         "name":"Ted",
         "surname":"Mosby",
         "age":35
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible remove the malformed element from the list using a custom typeadapter / deserialization using gson library?
If yes, what is the best approach?

Comment: Which one is the _malformed element_? Your JSON is not best example of problem because there should not be any difficulties deserializing whether age was `Int` or `String` in model class. Json itself does not state it to be some specific type but the class you are deserializing it into. The best approach I think is dependent on the actual problem. With `JsonParser` you can do anything in general but it might not be the most elegant way and you might want to use it only as the last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using a custom `TypeAdapter` as it lets you decide what to do with the tokens returned by the `JsonReader`.

Assuming you have a type `Response` representing the JSON string you pasted above (something similar to `class Result(val people: List<Person>)`), I think the key point here is to provide a `TypeAdapter<List<Person>>`, as that would allow you filtering out the invalid `Person` objects – you can't simply create a `TypeAdapter<Person>` that returns a `null` value for invalid `Person` objects as `people` was defined a list of non-nullable objects (i.e., `List<Person>` instead of `List<Person?>`.

A proof of concept for the above is:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val surname: String, val age: String)
class Result(val people: List<Person>)

fun main() {
    val json = """
        {
           "people":[
              {
                 "name":"Jon",
                 "surname":"Snow",
                 "age":"34"
              },
              {
                 "name":"Ted",
                 "surname":"Mosby",
                 "age":35
              },
              {
                 "name":"John",
                 "surname":"Smith",
                 "age": "40"
              }
           ]
        }""".trimIndent()

    val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(PersonListTypeAdapterFactory).create()

    val result = gson.fromJson(json, Result::class.java)
    println("Deserialized: ${result.people}")
    println("Serialized: ${gson.toJson(result)}")
}

object PersonListTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T : Any?> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        if (type.rawType != List::class.java || (type as? ParameterizedType)?.actualTypeArguments?.contains(Person::class.java) == false) {
            return null
        }
        val delegate: TypeAdapter<List<Person>> = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type) as TypeAdapter<List<Person>>
        return PersonListTypeAdapter(delegate) as TypeAdapter<T>
    }
}

class PersonListTypeAdapter(private val delegate: TypeAdapter<List<Person>>) : TypeAdapter<List<Person>>() {

    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: List<Person>) {
        delegate.write(out, value)
    }

    override fun read(input: JsonReader): List<Person> {
        input.beginArray()
        val people = mutableListOf<Person>()
        while (input.peek() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            val person = readPerson(input)
            if (person != null) {
                people.add(person)
            }
        }
        input.endArray()

        return people
    }

    private fun readPerson(input: JsonReader): Person? {
        input.beginObject()

        // initialising everything with nulls is a bit ugly
        var name: String? = null
        var surname: String? = null
        var age: String? = null

        var token = input.peek()
        while (token != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            when (input.nextName()) {
                "name" -> name = input.nextString()
                "surname" -> surname = input.nextString()
                "age" -> {
                    token = input.peek()
                    age = if (token == JsonToken.STRING) {
                        input.nextString()
                    } else {
                        input.skipValue()
                        // logging if needed
                        null
                    }
                }
            }
            token = input.peek()
        }
        input.endObject()

        if (listOf(name, surname, age).none(Objects::isNull)) {
            return Person(name!!, surname!!, age!!)
        }
        return null
    }

}
```

That code would print:

```
Deserialized: [Person(name=Jon, surname=Snow, age=34), Person(name=John, surname=Smith, age=40)]
Serialized: {"people":[{"name":"Jon","surname":"Snow","age":"34"},{"name":"John","surname":"Smith","age":"40"}]}
```

I'm pretty sure there's a lot of space for improvement